# Alias for cmd.exe or ConEmu with filename without extension as argument

Tags: windows, command-line, conemu

I'd like to create `alias` to run a program. My alias is as follows: `alias cc=g++ -Wall -Wextra $1 -o $1`. This way I could write `cc app.cpp` and the command would be `g++ -Wall -Wextra app.cpp -o app.exe`

**However, there is a problem.**

`$1` give filename with extension but I need only filename. Is there a workaround? `doskey` and `ConEmu` don't have a variable for a filename without extension. Such a variable has for example `for` in `cmd.exe`. It is `%A`.

Comment: [Batch Extract path and filename from a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable)

Comment: Just use a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be easy as @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 has provided useful link. Just create a bat file and paste this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for %%i in (%1) do (set filename=%%~ni)
g++ -Wall -Wextra %1 -o %filename%.exe
```

Tested and it works fine.